# Configuring GraphicMagick 1.3.19 in Cygwin

Tags: cygwin, octave, graphicsmagick

I'm trying to use Octave instead of MATLAB in order to run the Motion tracking software found here :

http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/~wauthier/tracker/

To run octave I am using Cygwin. I've run into the issue that the GraphicsMagick configuration  that comes with Cygwin is set to: --with-quantum-depth=16 when I need: --with-quantum-depth=32. I have installed and configured the same version of GraphicsMagick elsewhere on my computer. My question is how can I configure the pre-existing GraphicsMagick so that I may handle the larger images I need or how can I configure octave inside Cygwin to use the other install of GraphicsMagick.
While Searching I came upon this:

http://jethomson.wordpress.com/2010/08/22/enable-octave-to-read-16-bit-images/

I am hesitant to use this as it uses Debian and I am unsure how to modify it in order to work in Cygwin. 
Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: doing this will require that you rebuild GraphicsMagick and then Octave from source. Also, will your images be floating point or uint32? Rebuilding everything will only solve your problem with they are uint32 as GraphicsMagick does not really handle floating point images.

Comment: I am pretty sure they are uint32. How would I go about rebuilding? Would I go through the Cygwin setup, uninstall all dependencies that use GraphicsMagick, and then what? Would I need to find the folder containing their source and use make? I am a little unfamiliar on how Cygwin installs all the libraries and dependencies. The images are png format, if that helps. Also, thank you for replying.

Comment: I wrote the instructions for building of [GM](http://wiki.octave.org/GraphicsMagick) and [Octave](http://wiki.octave.org/Debian) in Debian but have no idea how they'll work in windows.

Comment: Darn, well I'll work through it. My main issue is unfamiliarity with the install process. I'll try to use the instructions you wrote for Debian and adapting them, might end up having to set up a linux box.